# PayPal API in C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, paypal

I am implementing windows form application in C# which uses Paypal API to get transaction details from Paypal. I am getting it in every time interval for which i have implemented Windows Service, its successfully getting transaction details from Paypal and updating local database. Is there any way i can get only New transaction details instead of getting all transaction? I know that we can apply filter at database while inserting by transaction no., and retrieve transaction through start and end date, but every time retrieving large transaction i don't think is a good solution.

Comment: What have you tried?  As for the underline question you would need to apply a filter on the result you get.

Comment: after applying filter it will definitely give the non duplicated result, but i want only new transactions to be returned from paypal, instead of getting all transactions.

Comment: Check the PayPal SDK/API if there isn't anything in the documentation then you need to get all the transactions and then simply filder the results on your end.  Since you have not provided any code there isn't else I can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason the database can't be updated before the request is sent to PayPal? The typical process I see is:

- Log the form data in the Database.
- Submit the request to PayPal
- Update the record based on the approval or denial from PayPal

This way all payments will be updated real-time and there won't be any need to get all transaction details within a specific time frame.